# firefox memory leak

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, memory-leaks, raphael

I have the following script (I use raphaeljs also) that draws a circle, waits 1 second, draws circle again, etc (you can copy paste it - is functional, only need to include raphael from raphaeljs.com):

```
<div id="holder">

</div>  
<script src="raphael.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
    var rad = Math.PI / 180;
    var finAngle = 0;
    function sector(cx, cy, r, startAngle, endAngle, params) {
            var x1 = cx + r * Math.cos(-startAngle * rad),
            x2 = cx + r * Math.cos(-endAngle * rad),
            y1 = cy + r * Math.sin(-startAngle * rad),
            y2 = cy + r * Math.sin(-endAngle * rad);
        return ["M", cx, cy, "L", x1, y1, "A", r, r, 0, +(endAngle - startAngle > 180), 0, x2, y2];
    }

    var path = sector(100,100,50,0,180);
    var arc = paper.path(path);

    function draw()
    {
        path = sector(100,100,50,0,finAngle);
        arc.attr({"path": path});

        finAngle += 1;
        /*
        if (finAngle == 360)
            finAngle = 359;
        */
        if (finAngle > 360)
        {           
            clearInterval(interval);
            setTimeout("setNewInterval();", 1000);
            finAngle = 1;
        }

        return;
    }

    function setNewInterval()
    {
        interval = setInterval("draw();", 3);
    }
    var interval = setInterval("draw();", 3);

</script>
```

The problem is that it seem to generate a memory leak on firefox (I let it run for like 10 min and firfox got to 700MB of ram (chrome stayed at 25MB)). Chrome has no problems with it.

Any ideas how I fix that?

Comment: Consider submitting a Firefox bug report

Comment: Did... but this doesn't really solves my problem :). I'm looking to modify the script but... I don't really know how since I can't see any problems there.

Comment: Which version of Firefox? Have you tried if with Firefox Nightly? Do you have the same issue? You can also use `about:memory` to trace better where this incrementation of memory happens, and try to force the GC and minimize the usage of the memory. Even if it's not probably relevant, I suggest to you to pass the function ref to the `setInterval` / `setTimeout`, not a string, e.g.: `setInterval(draw, 3)`. Take also in account that there is a chance that could be a browser bug or library bug, therefore your code can't do much.

Comment: Firefox 12.0. Only here I have the issue. Passed as ref, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some sort of odd GC heuristic issue.  I filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=761893

In the meantime, the best you can do is to find what's allocating those tens of megabytes of strings per second and not doing that...